# Erro ao conectar a banco Firebird com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebird

Estou tentando conectar a um banco de teste Firebird com NodeJS, e estou utilizando o pacote [`node-firebird`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird), e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
node index.js
Error: Connection is closed.
    at exports.Connection.Connection._queueEvent (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3117:22)
    at exports.Connection.Connection.connect (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3152:10)
    at C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:1587:13
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:2828:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\index.js:19
    db.query('SELECT * FROM TEST', function(err, result) {
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\index.js:19:8
    at doError (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:1244:9)
    at C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:1589:17
    at exports.Connection.Connection._queueEvent (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3117:13)
    at exports.Connection.Connection.connect (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3152:10)
    at C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:1587:13
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JEFTER\Documents\firebird-node-dev\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:2828:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
```

Estrutura

```
┌─data
│ └─TEST.FDB
├─node_modules
├─index.js
├─package.json
└─package-lock.json
```

index.js

```
const firebird = require('node-firebird')
const options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3050,
    database: 'C:/Users/JEFTER/Documents/firebird-node-dev/data/TEST.FDB',
    user: 'SYSDBA',
    password: 'masterkey',
    lowercase_keys: false, // set to true to lowercase keys
    role: null,            // default
    pageSize: 4096         // default when creating database
}

firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
 
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
 
    // db = DATABASE
    db.query('SELECT * FROM TEST', (err, result) => {
        // IMPORTANT: close the connection
        db.detach()
    })
})
```

A versão do Firebase é a 2.5x, estou usando Windows 10.

O banco `TEST.fbd` tem uma table `TEST` com 2 usuários com `id` e `nome`.

Comment: Consegue informar como você conecta neste mesmo banco na sua ferramenta de administração de banco ou algo assim para conferirmos as informações?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Bom dia! Tive esse mesmo problema ao conectar o firebird 3.0 a uma aplicação node.js em duas maquinas com linux (debian e ubuntu) , o que funcionou para mim foi alterar as configurações no arquivo firebird.conf.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Tente sem todas essas informações de configuração para ver se não é um problema de conflito de informações:

```
const firebird = require('node-firebird');
const configuracoes = {
  database: 'C:/Users/JEFTER/Documents/firebird-node-dev/data/TEST.FDB',
  user: 'SYSDBA',
  password: 'masterkey',
};

const pool = firebird.pool(5, configuracoes);

const executar = (query) => {
  return new Promise((resolver, rejeitar) => {
    pool.get((err, db) => {
      if (err) {
        rejeitar(err);
        return;
      }

      db.query(query, (erro, resultado) => {
        if (erro) {
          rejeitar(err);
          return;
        }

        db.detach();
        resolver(resultado);
      });
    });
  });
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await executar('SELECT * FROM TEST'));
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

No database o diretório da base tem que possuir duas barras "//" ao invés de "/" para o node aceitar.
Deve ficar assim: database: 'C://Users//JEFTER//Documents//firebird-node-dev//data//TEST.FDB'

Comment: Isso serve apenas para diretórios do Windows, onde a barra é invertida, sendo "\" ao invés de "/", pois a barra "\" serve como indicador de caractere especial, por isso o uso de barras duplas. Nas barras "/" que geralmente são usadas em SOs baseados em Unix, não é necessário elas serem duplas. De acordo com o exemplo do OP, como o diretório tem uma letra de drive, podemos assumir que é Windows, por tanto, a tua resposta se torna incorreta.